# How to make tab's item to be created programmatically?

Tags: qt, qml

I dynamically add tabs to `TabView` and pass tab's item to c++ for futher processing. The problem is that method `tabview.getTab(tabview.getTab(tabview.count-1).item)` returns `null` for the which index is >0. Here is code:

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    signal tabAdded(variant c)
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        TabView{
            visible: true
            id:tabview
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        Button{
            text: "add tab"
            onClicked:{
                var c = Qt.createComponent("Tab.qml");
                tabview.addTab("tab", c)
                // tabAdded(tabview.getTab(tabview.count-1).item)
                console.log(tabview.getTab(tabview.count-1).item)
        }
     }
  }

}

//Tab.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Item{
    signal tabButtonClicked()
    anchors.fill: parent
    Button{
       text: "tabButton"
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       onClicked: tabButtonClicked()
    }

}
```

I figured out that `tabview.getTab(index).item` returns apropriate value if tab(index) was activated manually (by clicking with mouse on it). It seems like tab's item is created only when user firstly activate tab. So, how to make item to be created immediately after tab creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every tab in *TableView* is represented by a *Tab* component that inherits from [*Loader* component](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html). If you want force the Tab to load its contents, just set [**active** property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#active-prop) to true. This property controls when the component must be loaded. So now, your button code looks like this:

```
Button{
    text: "add tab"
    onClicked:{
        var c = Qt.createComponent("Tab.qml");
        tabview.addTab("tab", c);
        var last = tabview.count-1;
        tabview.getTab(last).active = true; // Now the content will be loaded
        console.log(tabview.getTab(last).item);
    }
```

I hope this help you.